# Permission denied (publickey) Git Bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-key

На проде через гит деплоюсь с битбакета.

Поставил SSH-ключи (pub на битбакете, закрытый - в /home/user/.ssh).
Все работает.

Но стоит отключиться от прода по ssh, потом снова подключиться, как при pull получаю ошибку

"Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly".

Пока решается удалением старых ключей из /home/user/.ssh и перегенерацией новых с повторным добавлением pub-ключа на битбакет.

Мне кажется, это не должно так работать.

Как решить глобально эту проблему?

Comment: Не уверен что это решение проблемы с пониманием причины, но можно посоветовать не использовать пользователя под которым вы управляете машиной прода для аутентификации как система...лучше создать системного пользователя без пароля и уже под ним выполнять обращения к битбакету

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как под ним выполнять обращения к битбакету. Т.е., коннектиться на серв под ним? Но если нет пароля, как это делать?

Comment: Похоже я не правильно понял вопрос...мне показалось сначала что деплой происходит средствами CI...
Правильно ли я понимаю что деплой происходит следующим образом:
1. вы заходите на прод сервер под своим пользователем
2. вызываете git pull
3. выполняете некую команду обновления
И проблема возникает на втором шаге после деплоя очередного обновления...

Comment: И еще вопрос. имя ключа как я понимаю не стандартное id_rsa?

Comment: Да, сразу после git pull ... получаю ошибку "Permission denied (publickey)". Имя ключа bitbucket_rsa. Дело в том, что все работает до первого дисконнекта моего от прода. Как только снова войду по ssh и сделаю pull - вот тут и ошибка с правами...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том что ваш ключ после повторного захода не добавлен в список ключей ssh. Одним из вариантов решения каждый раз после захода на сервер выполнять команду ssh-add.

Еще возможен вариант прописать ключ как поле IdentityFile в .ssh/config. Пример конфига в этом случае будет следующий.

```
Host companyname.bitbucket.org
     HostName bitbucket.org
     User prod_deployer
     Port 4242
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa.key
```

Comment: Второй вариант работает (1-й не проверял). Еще пришлось выполнить команду ssh -T git@bitbucket.org, правда, не проверял, обязательна ли она.